# How to cite multiple authors without semicolon

Tags: apacite, multiple-citations

I want to cite multiple authors, using this formula:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \citeauthor{author1,author2,author3}.
\end{document}
```

The result is:

> Lorem ipsum author1;author2;author3.

Is there any way to obtain this result?: (note: "," instead of ";" and "y" in spanish):

> Lorem ipsum author1, author2 y author3.

Comment: Have you tried `\citeauthor{author1}, \citeauthor{author2} y \citeauthor{author3}`?

Comment: Yes, maybe this is the solution...

Answer (score 1):

If the three entries have citation keys `key1`, `key2`, and `key3`, I think you can't go wrong with simply writing

```
... \citeauthor{key1}, \citeauthor{key2} y \citeauthor{key3} ...
```

Comment: The problem is that I would like to update automatically all the citations of my dissertation without making changes in each case...anyway, I'll do what you suggest